# __attribute__() macro and its effect on Visual Studio 2010 based projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, gcc, macros, compiler-errors, legacy-code

I have some legacy code that has got conditional preprocessing e.g. `#ifdef` and `#else` where I have found the use of `__attribute__` macro. I have done a quick research and found out that it is specific to GNU compilers. I have to use this legacy code in Visual Studio 2010 using MSVC10 compiler and apparently it is complaining everywhere it sees **attribute**((unused)) even though it is protected by `#ifndef` and `#ifdef`s. An example is:

```
#ifdef __tone_z__
  static const char *mcr_inf
#else
  static char *mcr_inf
#endif
#ifndef _WINDOWS
__attribute__(( unused ))    % this is causing all the problem!!
#endif
= "@(#) bla bla copyright bla";



#ifdef __tone_z__
   static const char *mcr_info_2a353_id[2]
#else
   static       char *mcr_info_2a353_id[2]
#endif
__attribute__(( unused )) = { "my long copyright info!" } ;
```

I am really struggling to understand if it is very poorly planned code or is it just my misunderstanding. How do I avoid the usual compiler and linker errors with this `__attribute__()` directive? I have started to get C2061 errors (missing identifiers/unknown). I have got all necessary header files and nothing is missing, may be except GNU compiler (which I don't want!!).

Also, it seems that the end of line character `;` is also being messed up when I take to code in windows....argh....I mean the UNIX end-of-line and Windows EOL how can I use this code without modifying the body....I can define in my property sheet about the _WINDOWS thingy, but cannot automatically adjust the EOL character recognition.

ANy help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Note that `__attribute__` is not a macro. Just make sure you `#define _WINDOWS 1` when compiling on windows.

Comment: @MarcGlisse     thanks...that's is what I was hoping for. I was using Visual Studio 2010 where if you press CTRL+<SPACE> you can see all the predefined function attributes and macros allowed - _WINDOWS is not there. I will do that either in the property sheet or on my main method runner file.

Comment: You probably wanted `#ifndef _MSC_VER` instead of `#ifndef _WINDOWS`. There exists a define named `_WINDOWS_` (but note the additional trailing underscore) when you include `<windows.h>`, but generally the way to distinguish GCC/MSVC is through `GCC` and `_MSC_VER` defines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My best guess is that `_WINDOWS` is, in fact, *not* defined by your compiler, and so use of `__attibute__` is *not* protected.

In my opinion, the best way to protect against attributes is to define a macro like this:

```
#define __attribute__(A) /* do nothing */
```

That should simply remove all `__attribute__` instances from the code.

In fact, most code that has been written to be portable has this:

```
#ifdef _GNUC
  #define ATTR_UNUSED __attribute__((unused))
#else
  #define ATTR_UNUSED
#endif

static TONE_Z_CONST char *integ_func ATTR_UNUSED = "my copyright info";
```

(Other `__tone_z__` conditional removed for clarity only.)

Comment: It didn't work! I have done sufficient google research and nothing seems to be solving this problem. All I need is to use the legacy code written for GNU C compiler and put it on Visual Studio 2010. I have also updated the code snippet!

Comment: The MicroSoft compiler just isn't going to accept any `__attribute__` keywords or any other GNU extension; even some standard C/C++ is questionable. You're going to have to remove all that stuff, either manually, or via the preprocessor. I've shown you some ways how. It's really not that hard.